# React JS - Get all dom element id's in an array which are currently visible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, viewport

I was trying to get the id's of Card Component that is rendered in a map within a parent view component.

What I am trying to do is get all the ids of the visible cards in an array to make api calls.

I don't understand how to do that in React. Any Help would be appreciated.

```
class ParentView extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
          idList: [],
       }
   }
   componentDidMount() {
       this.props.getData();// Fetch necessary data and store in redux
   }
   render(){
      this.props.data.map((item, index)=>{
        <ChildComponent key={index} renderData={item}/>
      }
   }

}
```

In the above code snippet when it renders it fetches me from 0 to upto 300+ cards. Which is rendered in a grid view of 6 cards per row.

Each card has an id associated with it. What I need to know is when I scroll through the parent view I need to update the state idList with id's of ChildComponent currently in the View Port.

I have no idea on how to implement this in React JS.

I have tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-in-viewport but doesn't help in getting the id's of ChildComponent .

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: Can you share some code, what you have tried

Comment: I have made use of react-in-viewport npm module but its only meant to check if a component is in View Port https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-in-viewport

Comment: You have to manually calculate the records within the viewport using the current scrolled pixels, the height of each row and the height of the view port.

Comment: @jdc91 Do you have any example implementation any guide or link to a similar scenario in React or javascript. If possible do share it.

Comment: Checkout this implementation for react-window. It renders the elements within a specific view port. https://github.com/bvaughn/react-window/blob/master/src/FixedSizeGrid.js

Comment: Why do you need this anyway? Seems like a very strange requirement?

Comment: @jdc91 the req is I need to make a request from the front end every second to get real time data for each user for all cards. But making a request for 60 cards every seconds is wasteful. Instead if I have id's of these cards currently in the users view it will reduce the network requests being made.